# Why should we use a List of a particular type in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, static, format

I am currently going through a lesson in Java, and this lesson covers passing an `ArrayList` object through a static method. In the first static method, you see that `ArrayList` only had to be declared as `ArrayList`, and a name for it. The first static method displays all of the elements in the array. The second static method changes the elements of an `ArrayList`. When declaring the `ArrayList` in this method, it must be declared as `ArrayList<Integer>` for modification purposes. Why is it this way, and why does it make a difference? Thank you for anybody willing to shed light on this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Chap11Part5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //For-Loop to create elements for the ArrayList
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
            numbers.add(i);

        display(numbers); //Display Elements
        change(numbers, 5); //Change Elements (See "change" method)
        display(numbers); //Display New Results


    }

    //Loop to display elements of ArrayList
    static void display(ArrayList arr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
            System.out.print(arr.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    //Loop to change elements of ArrayList
    static void change(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int amount) {
        int value;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
            value = arr.get(i);
            arr.set(i, value + amount);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to know why it is displayed as ArrayList<Integer>. I don't understand why it's not showing up the right way in my question. I apologize.

Comment: This code is using a raw type, and it shouldn't. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<>` syntax is called [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) - it allows you to limit what type of elements a collection holds, and refer to them by this type. It's not required, it's just more convenient.

For instance, you could write the second method without any generics specified, but you'd have to handle the casting yourself:

```
static void change(ArrayList arr, int amount) {
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        value = (Integer) arr.get(i); // explicit casting here. Yuck!
        arr.set(i, value + amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I am understanding you, I never had to use "ArrayList<Integer>" when declaring inside the method. I still do not quite understand if "(Integer)" is even necessary at all. Could the line just be written as "value = arr.get(i);" or must the integer be declared somewhere inside the method?

Comment: You need the cast to `Integer` so the value can be unboxed to an `int`, as `value` is defined. If you didn't need to perform mathematical operations on it, you could definitely have used `Object value = arr.get(i)`.

Comment: @JeffSours you should never use raw types. Use `ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<?>`, but not `ArrayList`. Read the link I posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of [Java Generics API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). If you declare  as a type that collection will accept only that type of elements.

This solves the problem of handling ClassCastException problem where we used to handle casting explicitely.

```
 value = (Integer) arr.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a `List` for a particular type (that is `ArrayList<Integer>` your mentioned) will remove the risk of `ClassCastException` at runtime.